# Preventing page requests during WebSphere startup

Tags: deployment, websphere, race-condition, websphere-6.1, autodeploy

**Problem:** Pages requested prior to full application initialization cause application running under WebSphere  to have problems.

**Idea:** Prevent requests until the application is ready.

**Environment:** WebSphere ND 6.1.0.23 running on an application server machine, WebSphere plug-in for the application running on a separate web server machine.  Automatic nightly deployments in a QA test system often fail to initialize properly when pages are requested during application restarts.

**Question:** Is there a way to "turn off" requests at the WebSphere plug-in level before a redeployment starts, then "turn on" requests after the deployment?  If so, how would that be done?  For instance, is it possible to change the WebSphere web plugin xml and force a read of the new configuration file?  So far it seems that's only examined at application startup.

Answer (score 0):

The hard way to do this at the application server layer is to stop the http channel transport chain:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftrun_chain_disable.html

The best way would be to stop the traffic flow at the web layer i.e. the webserver or a front up load balancer.